# How to make fetch promise resolve without using .then syntax?

Tags: javascript, promise, es6-promise, fetch-api, isomorphic-fetch-api

First things first, I made sure to write a quick demo of the issue I'm talking about here https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-swirles-7cs3s

But essentially, using the `isomorphic-fetch` library, I'm running into an issue where I can't really get the value, or you might say, resolution, of the `fetch()` function.

```js
import fetch from "isomorphic-fetch";

async function test() {
  return await fetch("https://google.com", { mode: "no-cors" });
}

let t = test();
console.log(t);
```

The outcome of which is

[image]

Now I've also considered the other way of using `fetch()` like this

```js
fetch("https://google.com", { mode: "no-cors" })
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(data => console.log(data));
```

which actually delivers a string, but I prefer doing it the first way, if possible? It's also very possible I'm not using fetch correctly.

Comment: You cannot turn something asynchronous into synchronous without blocking.

Comment: so how do i block? @Derek朕會功夫

Comment: `mode: "no-cors"` is certainly not what you want https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41921805/fetch-api-to-get-html-response/41921909#41921909

Comment: it works without `"no-cors"` on my computer, i just had to add it for codesandbox @Kaiido

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try it like this:

```
import fetch from "isomorphic-fetch";

async function test() {
  const response = await fetch("https://google.com", { mode: "no-cors" });
  return response.text();
}
async function main() {
  let t = await test();
  console.log(t);
}
main();
```

You need to await the promise, and that means you need an async function.

Comment: do most programmers avoid this syntax? it seems a bit over the top to write two async functions to block? + return the output of just one request. i just want to do what's best practice

Comment: @notacorn if you're within an `async` function, you can use `await`. If not, you use `then()`.

Comment: Choose your poison @notacorn. .thens are awkward, but the only alternative is async-await, which requires the wrapping function. In this case you could of course just collapse the two functions into one.

Comment: i actually found an interesting article written on this topic (which i wouldnt have known how to google for without your help). https://hackernoon.com/6-reasons-why-javascripts-async-await-blows-promises-away-tutorial-c7ec10518dd9 @seesharper

Comment: Good summary, and fun fact, it was Microsoft's C# team that invented this syntax.

Answer (score 0):

fetch will return a promise, not a string. In your second example you call `.text()` on it. You will have to do something similar in asyc/await

Comment: even when I pass the outcome of `await fetch` into a variable and then return it with `text()` it still console logs as a pending promise

Answer (score 0):

Use `t.then(res => console.log(res));` it will return `response` object.

As you have `async` function `test` and you are not `await`ing it like `await test()` so it will return `promise`.

As per your comment you should be using `await test()`. But you can only use `await` inside `async` so I suggest to use wrapper function like below.

```
import fetch from "isomorphic-fetch";

async function test() {
  return await fetch("https://google.com", { mode: "no-cors" });
}

async function wrapper() {  
  let t = await test();
  console.log(t.text());
}

wrapper();
```

Comment: i think you fundamentally misunderstood and didn't read my question - first of all im trying to get the `text()` out of it, and second in my question I already show I know this syntax but I want to know how to do it the other way